# Conflict with db_set_active and variable_get

Tags: database, i18n-l10n, multi-sites

I am running a drupal multi-site system, with shared code and seperated DB. Each individual multi-site represents one continent and can have different language versions.

**What i want:**
I am working on a module, that gathers all available languages on all multi-sites into one big continent/language map.

To query cross-multi-site data i use `db_set_active([multisite])` and manually fetch some data via `db_query()`.

```
foreach ($multisites as $multisite) { 
  db_set_active($multisite['db']); //switch context
  $links = db_query(Select language from {languages} etc...)) // run query
  do_somthing_with_data($links) //work with data
  db_set_active(); //switch to default
}
```

This works pretty fine, 
but there are already drupal-core functions in `language.inc` i want to use (e.g. `language_negotiation_get_switch_links()`).

```
foreach ($multisites as $multisite) { 
  db_set_active($multisite['db']); //switch context
  $links = language_negotiation_get_switch_links(...,...) // run core-function
  db_set_active(); //switch to default
}
```

**Here is my problem:**
Several core functions use `variable_set()` and `variable_get()`. They are persistent and initialized on bootstrap.

When changing the active database with `db_set_active()`, incoming queries have the new context, but values fetched with `variable_get()` are inconsistent, because they store data from default database, filled on bootstrap.

**In a nutshell:**
I want to run core-functions on one multi-site with data from another multi-site. `db_set_active()` works fine, but data is inconsistent because `variable_get()` uses data, which is initialized on bootstrap.

Has anyone ever worked with this issue?

Kind regards
larry

**Addition:**

As I got deeper into development it became more and more complicated. I don't recommend the procedure of cross-multi-site-core-function-calling, because the initialization of core-functionality is triggered during bootstrap.

Here an example:

The multi-site you are browsing to does not need to initialize language.inc, because it has just one language-version. Further in code-progress you switch context to a multi-site with two or more languages but language.inc functionality is not available, because it was not initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been reading around, and on [`db_set_active`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_set_active/7)  API page on d.o the 2 comments on that page mention the problem with caches and multi dbs.

So I went on to look at [`variable_get`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) API page and it uses `global $conf` variable. I did a quick search on google on how to "refresh global variables conf" and got this page on d.o [`DrupalWebTestCase::refreshVariables()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!simpletest!drupal_web_test_case.php/function/DrupalWebTestCase%3A%3ArefreshVariables/7). Basically this function refreshes the global variables like so:

```
protected function refreshVariables() {
  global $conf;
  cache_clear_all('variables', 'cache_bootstrap');
  $conf = variable_initialize();
}
```

So I'm guessing (I haven't tried it and I don't have a multisite installation at hand to test it) you just need to utilise the code from the above function and clear the variables cache and re-initialize the variables in your foreach loop. I'm not sure how efficient it is so that's another issue if it's not efficient and slows down your page.

```
global $conf;
foreach ($multisites as $multisite) { 
  // Not sure if cache_clear_all should be called before or after switching the database. You should test and figure out what's best.
  cache_clear_all('variables', 'cache_bootstrap');
  db_set_active($multisite['db']); //switch context
  // Re-set $conf global variable so when variable_get gets called it uses the updated $conf.
  $conf = variable_initialize();
  $links = language_negotiation_get_switch_links(...,...) // run core-function
  db_set_active(); //switch to default
}
```

Hope this helps steer you in the right direction. Good luck

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by overwriting only selected config values. Although your solution works as intended, the results are not as supposed. Still takes a lot of debugging.

Comment: Glad you got it working! Feel free to edit my answer and post your solution so the world can see. Or maybe add another answer and accept that as the answer as I'm quite curious to know this myself in case I encounter this in the future.